# Why using _ (undersocre) in numbers throw "Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number" Error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js

I am writing a Nextjs + typescript application (created with `npx create-next-app@latest --ts`) where i face the error of

```
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number
```

when using underscore to separate numeric digits like so:

```
 <p>{(15_5000_000).toLocaleString()}</p>
```

But writing the same line like below, will not throw the error and will work fine:

```
<p>{(155000000).toLocaleString()}</p>
```

The full error text is:

```
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (295:42)
File was processed with these loaders:
  * ./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|                             className: "text-16 font-m text-black",
|                             children: [
>                                 155000000.toLocaleString(),
|                                 " \u062A\u0648\u0645\u0627\u0646"
|                             ]
```

Why this error occurs and how can i fix it? (I want to use underscore to separate numeric digits because it makes numbers more readable.)

Comment: And which version of Node?

Comment: Can you post what version/config of Babel you're using? This is probably related to https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-numeric-separator .

Comment: node version: 16.13.0

Comment: @JeffBowman I haven't configured Babel manually so the project is using the default config of babel created by nextjs. (nextjs version: 12.2.0; react: 18.2.0)

Comment: This is most likely a bug with SWC. I'd suggest raising an issue in https://github.com/swc-project/swc/issues if it's not there yet. For an immediate solution, you can either not use the numeric separator for now; or use [Babel](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/customizing-babel-config) as the compiler  for Next.js instead.